# How to delete a custom metadata that is protected component via Apex or Metadata API

Tags: custom-object, metadata-api, custom

Anybody have experience doing this in Apex/Metadata API?

[image: Protected Component]

Answer (score 1):

Custom metadata type records that are part of a managed package and are protected cannot be deleted.

You'll find more information as a starting point in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_req_managed_pkgs.htm&type=5).